# OpenSSL verify fails unexpectedly with "permitted subtree violation" for certificate with Name Constraints

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I am trying to verify a PIV certificate from a smart card using a certificate that includes a Name Constraints extension.  If I inspect the `-text` output everything looks like it should be fine but the two values have different case.  Is it possible that OpenSSL is doing a case-sensitive comparison even though [rfc5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-7.2) indicates that it should be case-insensitive?  Here are the relevant text outputs:

Root CA (changed actual values to `example` but preserved casing:

```
            X509v3 Name Constraints: critical
                Permitted:
                  email:example.com
                  email:.example.com
                  DNS:example.com
                  DirName:C = US, O = Example
```

PIV Certificate (again, changed actual values to example)

```
       Subject: C = us, O = example, OU = people, CN = john.j.doe.123456
```

Here the `Subject` `C` and `O` values have a different case than those in the `DirName` constraint.

Here is the full output I'm getting from the `openssl verify`

```
$ openssl verify -noCAfile -CAfile root.crt -untrusted intermediate.crt piv-cert.crt
C = us, O = example, OU = people, CN = john.j.doe.123456
error 47 at 0 depth lookup: permitted subtree violation
error piv-cert.crt: verification failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not due to case; [`nc_dn` in v3_ncons.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509v3/v3_ncons.c#L530) calls the i2d routine which calls [`x509_name_canon` in x_name.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509/x_name.c#L290) which calls [`asn1_string_canon`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509/x_name.c#L384) which drops unnecessary spaces and converts to lowercase, before comparing.

It's (probably, given your redaction) due to an additional check that CommonName in the leaf cert if it 'looks like' a DNS name must satisfy the DNS constraints, which your example respectively does and doesn't.

Specifically, [`NAME_CONSTRAINTS_check_CN` in v3_ncons.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509v3/v3_ncons.c#L408) is called for the leaf/EE cert, and (now) calls [`cn2dnsid`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509v3/v3_ncons.c#L315) to check for DNS syntax (post-punycoding if applicable): all ASCII letters, digits, plus nonstandard underscore, plus dot not at beginning or end or consecutive (i.e. all DNS labels must be nonempty) plus hyphen not at beginning or end or adjacent to dot. If this passes it applies any DNS constraints.

This looks like it is intended for SSL/TLS server certificates -- and the commit that [added an earlier version to 1.1.0](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/5bd5dcd49605ca2aa7931599894302a3ac4b0b04) acknowledged 5280 doesn't call for CN check, while [this refactoring for 1.1.1](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/d02d80b2e80adfdde49f76cf7c7af4e013f45005) briefly modified it to apply only if no SAN DNS was present (and thus checked), but [immediately thereafter](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/55a6250f1e7336e8a7d89fb609eb23398715ff6f#diff-ff8caceb02802f5651bf57f7630a37c18b3af40e24ddb10303f75432947f5b02) that SAN bypass was removed from the code at the same time the documentation was changed to describe it as happening, which looks like a mistake to me -- but the code doesn't attempt to limit it to such server certs (and probably can't, because EKU is optional).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response.  Just so I'm sure I understand what you're saying, the CN attribute `john.j.doe.123456` looks like a DNS name so the constraints checking is checking that against the DNS constraint which specifies `example.com` and thus fails because `john.j.doe.123456` does not end in `example.com`.

Comment: Ben: yes, exactly

Comment: One more follow up - the PIV certificate _does_ have an Other Name -> Principle Name which ends in `example.com`.  I'm running `OpenSSL 1.1.1f` and if I understand your last paragraph correctly that version still ignores the SAN record.  You mention that this looks like a mistake to you.  Is this something that should be submitted as an issue?

Comment: All released versions 1.1.0 up do the CN check against DNS constraints regardless of SAN; the 2nd and 3rd commits I referenced were in '1_1_1-pre7' i.e. before release. (I meant 'for 1.1.1' to indicate that, but that probably wasn't clear.) I doubt OpenSSL does anything with an OtherName constraint , but that'll take more research; I'll try to get to it in a few days.